# A Lazy Sunday Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

For those of you lazing in the summer heat (or winter cold for my ANZAC friends!), a cryptic crossword. I would like to acknowledge using Crossword Compiler for help in creating the grid, but all clues are, for good or bad, my own. Happy solving!

[image: Grid]

[Plaintext version here](https://pastebin.com/dYSC3zvw)

**ACROSS**
8/17A. Woman in Crawley house describes city location (4,4)
9. Part of Shire topping The Hill small, a few tiny pieces (10)
10. Medium event invites TED leader for second opinion? (6)
11. Hormone N replacing nickel with einsteinium (8)
12. Applications decline after cutting official guarantees at termination (4)
13. Insect order came from A Cooler Pet mangled (10)
17. See 8-Across
18. Modify commercial fitting (5)
19. Nut we up-chucked for money (4)
20. Knight to king two: hung rook after finesse (4,6)
22. Country gal sheds top (4)
23. Advocated for Ed to take a wife (8)
27. Fisherman's accessory to murder; conclusion drawn from prison guards (6)
28. Knot in cotton or plastic (10)
29. Pale face last to fade (4)

**DOWN**
1. Innovative educator to set up studio boundaries in developing minor (10)
2. Radical seizes Northern schools concurrently (2,6)
3. Turn head of moving assistant (10)
4. Failed econ a long time ago (4)
5. Jog to burn off last bit of cake, turnover (4)
6. Able to raid indiscriminantly (6)
7. Pump filter? Use Hoover (4)
14. Disinclined to promise after last betrayal (5)
15. Getting to be too much in debt after Touareg, losing axle ends, crashes (10)
16. Place gold sun god on new top-shelf Thai eatery (10)
19. 100 who possessed, and 500 do possess, invitation to dine (4,4)
21. Cave painting's last sample of rose tint lining orange (6)
24. Reverse heading mid-day, almost (4)
25. Street to circle or straighten (4)
26. Endlessly, pride wounded for wimp (4)

Comment: What's ANZAC? Did you mean, "Australia, New Zealand, Argentina, Chile"?

Comment: ANZAC was the Australia New Zealand Army Corps that served nobly in the World Wars. I try to make ANZAC biscuits every April.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solved grid:

> [image]

Clue explanations:

> [image]

Overall, a nice puzzle! A few clues I want to mention:

> The "of" in 3D didn't quite make sense to me - this might be overtechnical, but I think "[def] of [wp]" is fine and "[wp] of [def]" isn't. (The definition is derived from the wordplay, after all.)
>
>  9A's "topping The Hill", 14D's "last betrayal", and 20A's "two hung" all seem to be reversed from their 'proper' grammatical order to me. Something like "betrayal last", using "betrayal" as a noun adjunct -- or even better, "betrayal's last" -- would be better in my eyes.
>
>  "filter" in 7D also didn't quite make sense to me. I'm not sure that's specific enough to be an "every other letter" indicator.
>
>  And to not be too negative, some praise for some of the clues:
>  18A's "commercial fitting" was nicely distracting! I love how both of those words read as the wrong part of speech in the surface.
>  22A and 23A both had interesting wordplay and a very clean surface - simple clues, but ones I definitely enjoyed.
>  And 10A's letter-change gimmick was clever and nicely disguised. I needed all three crossings before I realized "invites [...] for [...]" could be a replacement.

Comment: Nailed it, of course! Thanks for the compliments! Re: other comments, no real disagreement, but some explanation. 3D: rot13(jnf guvaxvat "urnq bs" nf qrs sbe "punve" irefhf "bs" nf pbaarpgbe). 9A: rot13(hfrq "gbccvat" nf n ireo "gb erzbir gur urnq sebz", yvxr gbccvat n gerr). 14D: I messed up. 20A: Got too enamored with the surface, but would probably do it again :-) 7D: Trying to reach for new indicator, maybe didn't hit. Thanks for the feedback!